# Feature test macros not working properly in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, macros

When testing for features in Visual Studio, I found this weird behaviour:

```
#ifndef __cpp_constexpr
#error Opposite day! //Compiler error
#endif

#define test_macro

#ifndef test_macro
#error But only for feature macros? //No compiler error
#endif

int main() {}
```

`__cpp_constexpr` is *definitely* defined, I used it in the actual program.
From my testing, it seems that with feature macros `#ifndef` behaves like `#ifdef`
and vice versa.

Is this a Visual Studio bug, or am I missing something?

Compiled in VS 2017, Visual C++14 or later, with C++17 standard enabled.

P.S. Intellisense is working as intended, it's only the compiler.

Comment: FWIW feature test macros also don’t seem to be properly supported by other compilers either; for instance, while GCC deals fine with `__cpp_constexpr`, it fails with others, such as `__cpp_lib_make_unique`. Effectively they seem to be unreliable and therefore don’t work for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect pre-defined macro and pre-proc code.  Next code can help:

```
#if defined(__GNUG__) && (__cplusplus > 201103L)
#  define HAS_CONSTEXPR
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_FULL_VER >= 190024210)
#  define HAS_CONSTEXPR
#endif // __GNUG__

#ifndef HAS_CONSTEXPR
#  error Opposite day! //Compiler error
#else
#   define test_macro
#   ifndef test_macro // useless by why not ? 
#     error But only for feature macros? //No compiler error
#   endif
#endif
```

Suggesting to use boost config library. It is cross compiler, an you can solve it like this:

```
#ifdef BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR
#   error Opposite day! //Compiler error
#endif
```

And it is going to work for all compilers supported by boost (according to the boost license, you can exam the source code and replicate is in you project)

Comment: I can always test for visual c++ version, but that's not cross-platform. Pretty sure that [feature test macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros) were introduced just for this reason. Also I can't use boost.

Comment: @andreasxp Feature test macro is nice. But "it is hard to use something, witch is not supported by your compiler" (c) Jeff Alger   :) I've done the update for gcc

Comment: @andreasxp  __cplusplus macro is not defined properly in MSVC++ (i have no idea why), so you have to use _MSC_FULL_VER checks

Comment: @VictorGubin Because they technically haven't had "full" C++11 support yet - see this blog post for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/